# Batch file connect to database server to get table in the form of CSV file to application server

Tags: sql, batch-file, application-server, database-server

I got a requirement on the batch file script but I am new to write the Batch file script.

Here is the requirement:

1. I have Application and Database servers.
2. Batch file run on Application server.
3. connect to Database server.
4. run the query present in the batch file in the table of the particular database in DB server.
5. output should be exported into a .csv(excel) file
6. .csv file should be transferred to App server folder
7. if possible maintain the log in app server on each action.

I have tried much to write the script from so many days but I am not able to do it even I have some script found through google.

```
@ECHO OFF <br/>
SQLCMD /? > nul 2> nul <br/>
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO.SQLCMD not found on this machine & PAUSE & GOTO :eof <br/><br/>

SET SQLCmdLine=SQLCMD -b -w400<br/>
REM use something like the next line for NT authentication; second line for SQL authentication<br/>
REM for NT SET SQLCmdLine=%SQLCmdLine% -E -S "YourServerName"<br/>
REM for SA SET SQLCmdLine=%SQLCmdLine% -U "YourSQLUserName" -P "YourSQLPassword" -S "YourServerName" <br/>
REM SET Database=YourDatabaseName <br/>
REM Matrix is my database name <br/>
SET Database=Matrix<br/><br/>

REM I will use NT Authentication for this example<br/>
SET SQLCmdLine=%SQLCmdLine% -E -S "(local)"<br/>
SET TestSQLCmdLine=%SQLCmdLine% -h-1 -d "%Database%"<br/><br/>

REM this will get the SQL version
%TestSQLCmdLine% -Q "SELECT @@VERSION" | FINDSTR /v "rows affected"

REM this will run a SQL script <br/>
%TestSQLCmdLine% -i "YourSQLScript.SQL" <br/>
PAUSE <br/>

REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>
REM Generic script for exporting data to file from SQL Server using a SQL query.<br/>
REM The resulting file will be tab separated with newline as the row delimiter.<br/>
REM A log file is generated and kept in case of an error or when in debug mode.<br/>
REM See command syntax for details.<br/>
REM<br/>
REM History:<br/>
REM 20120327    Lars Rönnbäck   CREATED<br/>
REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>
:constants<br/>
SET myCodePage=ACP<br/>
:variables<br/>
SET theQuery=SELECT  [D-U-N-S Number], [Company Name], [Street Address Line 1], [Street         Address Line 2], [Street Address Line 3], [Street Address Line 4], Town, [County (Actual)], [Full Postcode], [Telephone Number] FROM B2B_Jan13.dbo.DATA_HQ_1_Site_Level <br/>
SET theFile=C:\B2B_Matching_Automation\Temp_Files\Sites.csv<br/>
SET theServer=localhost<br/>
SET theDebug=%~4<br/>
SET /a aRandomNumber=%random%%%1000<br/>
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-7* delims=.:/,- " %%a IN (`ECHO %DATE%_%TIME%`) DO (SET myStartTime=%%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f%%g)<br/>
SET myColumnQuery="select top 0 * into [#columns_%myStartTime%_%aRandomNumber%] from (%theQuery%) q; <br/>
select stuff((select char(9) + c.name from tempdb.sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id order by c.column_id for XML path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1,1,'') AS Header from tempdb.sys.tables t where t.name like '#columns_%myStartTime%_%aRandomNumber%%%'" <br/>
SET myHeaderFile=%theFile%.%aRandomNumber%.header<br/>
SET myDataFile=%theFile%.%aRandomNumber%.data<br/>
SET myLogFile=%theFile%.%myStartTime%_%aRandomNumber%.log<br/>
:checks<br/>
IF "%theQuery%"=="" (<br/>
GOTO syntax<br/>
) <br/><br/>


----------<br/>


IF "%theFile%"=="" (<br/>
GOTO syntax<br/>
) <br/>
IF "%theServer%"=="" ( <br/>
SET theServer=%COMPUTERNAME%<br/>
)<br/>
:information<br/>
ECHO Start Time:    %myStartTime%       >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
ECHO Random Number: %aRandomNumber%     >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
ECHO File:          %theFile%           >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
ECHO Server Name:   %theServer%         >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
ECHO Query:                             >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
ECHO.                                   >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
ECHO %theQuery%                         >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
:export<br/>
BCP %myColumnQuery% queryout "%myHeaderFile%" -T -S "%theServer%" -a 65535 -c -C %myCodePage% -q >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error<br/>
BCP "%theQuery%" queryout "%myDataFile%" -T -S "%theServer%" -a 65535 -c -C %myCodePage% -q >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error<br/>
ECHO.                   >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
ECHO Merging files...   >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
ECHO.                   >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
COPY /A "%myHeaderFile%" + "%myDataFile%" "%theFile%" /B /Y >> "%myLogFile%" 2>&1<br/>
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error<br/>
:cleanup<br/>
DEL "%myHeaderFile%" >NUL 2>&1<br/>
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error<br/>
DEL "%myDataFile%" >NUL 2>&1<br/>
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error<br/>
IF /I NOT [%theDebug%]==[Y] (<br/>
DEL "%myLogFile%"<br/>
)<br/>
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error<br/>
GOTO end<br/>
:error<br/>
ECHO <br/>
ECHO ERROR: An export error has occured!<br/>
IF NOT [%myLogFile: =%]==[] (<br/>
  ECHO Details can be found in:<br/>
  ECHO %myLogFile%<br/>
)<br/>
ECHO <br/>
EXIT /B 1<br/>
:syntax<br/>
    ECHO.<br/>
ECHO SYNTAX: %0 "sql query" "output file" [server] [Y]<br/>
ECHO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>
ECHO You must specify an SQL query and an output file name in which the results of  <br/>
ECHO the query will be stored. Specifying a server is optional and defaults to the  <br/>
ECHO server you are executing on. If a fourth argument is given as Y a log file of<br/>
ECHO the command outputs will be saved in the same folder as the output file.<br/>
ECHO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>
```

Comment: If this is urgent then at least post the error that you are getting when you run the above script! If there is no error then post what you expect to happen! Saying it's urgent is a little rude. Saying it's urgent without any effort to troubleshoot or describe the problem is ruder.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I am sorry.. don't know about this script and I tried till connection  and after that I found the code from google search. I am not getting the code how it flows and works and I tried to contact many of my frnds they also don't know the batch file script. finally they suggested me to post over here for kind help.

Comment: This is a batch script. It's pretty complicated but basically it calls SQLCMD.EXE and uses that to connect and export a file. I suggest you start by looking through the script and replacing various parameters with yours i.e. NT or SQL authentication? Server Name, Database name, CSV file path, Log file path, SQL statement. Then run it and identify any errors. This is just a complicated looking batch file that calls `SQLCMD.EXE`